# C++ Accessing data list of a struct that contains a list of int's

Tags: visual-c++

I am trying to access a list within a list of structs and I can not figure out how to access the information.

```
struct pNode
{
    string name;
    list<int> mList;
};
list<pNode> pList;

for (auto pIt = pList.begin(); pIt != pList.end(); pIt++)
    for (auto mIt = pIt->mList.begin(); mIt != pIt->mList.end(); mIt++)
mIt->pIt->mList    ????
mIt->*(pIt->mList)    ????
mIt->(*pIt->mList)    ????
```

How do I access the information within mList? None of the above seem to work.

Comment: `*mIt` is the current `int` in the current `mList`, if that's what you are asking.

Comment: Correct:
pIt is the iterator that is pointing to a list of structs which contains the list mList. My intent is to cycle through the struct list to find a given name, then update the mList with an integer(s). 

The link below has 90% of this answered just it doesn't show how to code it.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31165044/access-list-elements-in-list-of-structs/47643980?noredirect=1#comment82246701_47643980

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the nature of the difficulty. If you want to examine or modify existing contents of `pIt->mList`, use `*mIt` (you can take its value, or assign to it). For example, `std::cout << *mIt;`. If you want to add new elements to `pIt->mList`, use `pIt->mList.push_back(42)` or similar.

Comment: Where is "here"?

Comment: Any chance I could email you my code? It will not let me edit my post, nor put 125 lines in a comment.